# training the same model with different data sets in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, dataset, models

The problem:
I have a model that I would like to train with independent data sets. Afterwards, I would like to extract the weights of each model (the model is the same for each instance but trained using different datasets) and finally, compute and average of these weights. Basically, my intention is to mimic tensorflow running on multiple devices and then average their weights so that they are used by one model.

My solution:
I added this model multiple times to tensorflow and am currently training each of these models separately with its unique dataset..  but this is using GBs of memory, and am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is that you can fine-tune your network weights with  other similar networks(similar datasets, i.e, if your dataset is images, you can use AlexNet weights)don't afraid if your network has no same architecture, you can simply load weights of layers as much as you need by 'load_with_skip' function of
https://github.com/joelthchao/tensorflow-finetune-flickr-style/blob/master/network.py

Fine-tuning takes much less than train networks from scratch.